# Uploading files to Sharepoint from Salesforce

Tags: rest, salesforce, integration, sharepoint-online, sfdc

I came to know that, through file connect one can only view Sharepoint files in Salesforce.

I am trying to Upload files to sharepoint from Salesforce and access them from salesforce. User uploads files in SalesForce. But it should actually save to SharePoint. User will not be knowing that, file is being saved in SharePoint and Only the Reference to the files will be in Salesforce

Comment: Can someone provide some input on this.

Answer (score 0):

With Document Extractor you can do what you need - once the file is uploaded in Salesforce a copy of the uploaded file will upload in SharePoint, then a link file pointing to that SharePoint location is created in Salesforce and the Salesforce is deleted. Here you can find more info on this topic: https://www.connecting-software.com/cb-salesforce-sharepoint-document-stubbing/ or https://www.connecting-software.com/blog/salesforce-data-cut-costs-boost-compliance/

Answer (score 0):

I come across one douglas Cayers repository which shows how we can make use of files connect for sending file to sharepoint. You can access his solution from

https://gist.github.com/douglascayers/d2af04aa597931168a17ce8f408ccbbb

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.